# How to send notifications with rules to users with access permission to view content?

Tags: rules, notifications, distributions

I have a rule to send an html mail when new content is created, but is not respecting the user permission to access content.

Is an Open Atrium site that works with OG. I have a space with 7 teams and only team members can view team contents (7 sections asociated to 7 teams). All users have the same role (filter by role is not a solution for me).

The content type in question have two entity reference fields: group audience and section (one per team).

In the rule I have an action to "Get group members" but I do not find the way to get only team members. If the solution is not with the teams may be something like filter or validate the value item-list:mail with the permission of the user to access to the content? It is possible to do something like that?

Any help is very apreciated, thanks!
[image: my rule]